# How to apply styles to a shadow element from within a css file

Tags: css, reactjs

I've got the following code, that's basically an Auth0 login form and it includes the logo image as an img element, which has it's own shadown tree: It looks like this:

```
<div class="auth0-lock-header-welcome">
    <img alt="" class="auth0-lock-header-logo" src="/supp/pixel.png">
       #shadow-root (user-agent)
         <span>
            <img />
         </span>
    <div class="auth0-lock-name" title="Log in">Log in</div>
</div>
```

How do I select the `<span>` in the #shadow-root, the `<img>` or even both in a classic .css file? Or do I have to write some React code for it?

Here's what I tried (none worked):

```
.auth0-lock-header .auth0-lock-header-logo::shadow #shadow-rootspan{
  display: none;
}

:host(.auth0-lock-header .auth0-lock-header-logo #alttext-image) {
  display: none;
}
```

PS: Sorry if it's a stupid question.

Comment: What is `#shadow-root (user-agent)` ?

Comment: I presume it's the root of the ShadowDOM tree that's been defined by Auth0 (this is not a login form that I've written).

Comment: OK, well those are not HTML tags so you cannot target that with CSS.  To target the span, I would think it would simply be `.auth0-lock-header-welcome span`

Comment: Unless those are special things that are actually generating valid html tags.  If that is the case, you need to look at the generated HTML and post that instead.